# ISI-Exam $2020$ PCB NC$7$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Problem: Let $A=\{1,2,\cdots, 50\}$. In how many ways can three distinct numbers $x<y<z$ be chosen from $A$ such that the product is divisible by $125$?

I have solved in the brute force manner, i.e. by considering the case by case method. I have got the answer $714$ ways.

For example:
if $z=50$, and $y= 46, 47, 48, \text{ or }49$, then $x$ has $9$ choices for each $y$. Therefore, total ways= $4\times 9 =36$.
Thus, if $z=50$ and $y\in \{1,2,3,4\}\text{ mod}5$ the total ways = $180$.

Similarly, for other ways.

Question: Is there any simple and cleaner way to approach this problem rather than a brute-force approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10 numbers are divisible by 5. Any choice of three of them works so $10 \choose 3$. Aside from these, you could include 1 of the 40 numbers not divisible by 5, forcing you to choose either, both of 25 and 50, or one of these and any of the 8 numbers only once divisible by 5.  Thus $ 40 \choose 1$ $ ( {2 \choose 2} + {2 \choose 1} {8 \choose 1 })$ more choices. Summing these give 800.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Seems pretty reasonable to make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

10 numbers are divisible by 5. Any choice of three of them works so $10 \choose 3$. Aside from these, you could include 1 of the 40 numbers not divisible by 5, forcing you to choose either, both of 25 and 50, or one of these and any of the 8 numbers only once divisible by 5. Thus ${40 \choose 1}\left({2 \choose 2}+{2\choose 1}{8 \choose 1}\right)$  more choices. Summing these give 800.